# Merge rows with unique ID in stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset where I need unique county FIPS codes that need to be merged. The dataset looks like:

```
FIPS yr1990 yr2000 yr2010
1001 1      0      1
1002 1      1      0
1003 1      0      0
1004 0      0      0
1005 0      0      1
```

County boundaries have changed and I need to merge several FIPS codes together. Essentially, I need the dataset to look like:

```
FIPS         yr1990 yr2000 yr2010
1001/1003   1       1      1
1002        1       1      0
1004/1005   0       0      1
```

Is there a way to select specific FIPS to be merged over rows?

Comment: The English word _merge_ is natural here, or at least unsurprising, but in Stata the   command `merge` is only to do with merging datasets, not observations (rows).  The Stata term of art is _collapse_ (or occasionally _contract_) with corresponding commands.

Answer (score 1):

This solution might not scale to very large datasets as writing the `replace` statements must be done manually. But it keeps the exact format you are using in your example. And a more scalable way might be difficult if there is no system in how the FIPS codes were combined.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str4 FIPS byte(yr1990 yr2000 yr2010)
"1001" 1 0 1
"1002" 1 1 0
"1003" 1 0 0
"1004" 0 0 0
"1005" 0 0 1
end

*Combine the FIPS codes
replace FIPS = "1001/1003" if inlist(FIPS,"1001","1003")
replace FIPS = "1004/1005" if inlist(FIPS,"1004","1005")

*Collapse rows by FIPS value, use max value for each var on format yr????
collapse (max) yr???? , by(FIPS)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would do. Just to spell it out, `collapse` collapses on identical values. There isn't a handle to add that while `collapse` is doing that, it should put together certain values and consider them as identical. You must define what you want to combine before the `collapse`.